# AngularJS How to remove # symbol in IE9 by using route

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-9, routes, using

I can't remove the # symbol in IE9. I searched for an answer but didn't find a fix.

This always redirects to

```
http://myhost.com:8080/#/website/
```

and shows this description:

```
The requested resource is not available.
```

`locationprovider.html5mode(true)` is not working.
The same route is working in FireFox and shows

```
http://myhost.com:8080/website/
```

How can I rectify this?

Comment: Hi there, did you resolve this issue? I'm having the exact same problem.

Comment: @TheLastBlackCat also looking for a solution to this.

Answer (score 6):

IE9 does not have html5 history api support, that's why it's appending # to the url, removing # will not solve your problem

Comment: thanks for answer. How can i resolve this Problem? Inserting /#/into /path/ in when is not working too... :(

Comment: @TheLastBlackCat I would use only # on your place. Switch off html5 mode :)

Answer (score 6):

[$location Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)

See "Hashbang and HTML5 modes"

Basically, html5 mode uses `History API` when the browser supports it, and falls back to hashbang(`#`) when it is not supported.

You cannot "just" remove "#" in a browser without History API. Because when you change the url, the browser would then try to force a reload, breaking the flow.

Answer (score 2):

In fact we can not remove that, but we can make it work smoothly

```
RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, { useHash: Boolean(history.pushState) === false });
```

Answer (score 0):

Using  `window.location.hash = '/'`  solved my problem.

```js
if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}
else {
        window.location.hash = '/'  // IE 9 FIX            
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}
```

Comment: In fact, angular can treat it in the right way if the browser don't support hte History API, "If the HTML5 History API is not supported by a browser, the $location service will fall back to using the hashbang URLs automatically." [$location api](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)