# Angular Routing Causes Infinite Loop In IE

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-8

I am receiving the following error when I look at my code in Internet Explorer 10 (it does not necessarily render in standards mode, this is out of my control due to the way the page is served).

[http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.28/$rootScope/infdig](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.28/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%22fn%3A%20function()%7Bvar%20a%3Dd.url()%2Cb%3Dh.%24%24replace%3Bn%26%26a%3D%3Dh.absUrl()%7C%7C(n%2B%2B%2Cc.%24evalAsync(function()%7Bc.%24broadcast(%5C%22%24locationChangeStart%5C%22%2C%5Cnh.absUrl()%2Ca).defaultPrevented%3Fh.%24%24parse(a)%3A(d.url(h.absUrl()%2Cb)%2Cg(a))%7D))%3Bh.%24%24replace%3D!1%3Breturn%20n%7D%3B%20newVal%3A%207%3B%20oldVal%3A%206%22%5D%2C%5B%22fn%3A%20function()%7Bvar%20a%3Dd.url()%2Cb%3Dh.%24%24replace%3Bn%26%26a%3D%3Dh.absUrl()%7C%7C(n%2B%2B%2Cc.%24evalAsync(function()%7Bc.%24broadcast(%5C%22%24locationChangeStart%5C%22%2C%5Cnh.absUrl()%2Ca).defaultPrevented%3Fh.%24%24parse(a)%3A(d.url(h.absUrl()%2Cb)%2Cg(a))%7D))%3Bh.%24%24replace%3D!1%3Breturn%20n%7D%3B%20newVal%3A%208%3B%20oldVal%3A%207%22%5D%2C%5B%22fn%3A%20function()%7Bvar%20a%3Dd.url()%2Cb%3Dh.%24%24replace%3Bn%26%26a%3D%3Dh.absUrl()%7C%7C(n%2B%2B%2Cc.%24evalAsync(function()%7Bc.%24broadcast(%5C%22%24locationChangeStart%5C%22%2C%5Cnh.absUrl()%2Ca).defaultPrevented%3Fh.%24%24parse(a)%3A(d.url(h.absUrl()%2Cb)%2Cg(a))%7D))%3Bh.%24%24replace%3D!1%3Breturn%20n%7D%3B%20newVal%3A%209%3B%20oldVal%3A%208%22%5D%2C%5B%22fn%3A%20function()%7Bvar%20a%3Dd.url()%2Cb%3Dh.%24%24replace%3Bn%26%26a%3D%3Dh.absUrl()%7C%7C(n%2B%2B%2Cc.%24evalAsync(function()%7Bc.%24broadcast(%5C%22%24locationChangeStart%5C%22%2C%5Cnh.absUrl()%2Ca).defaultPrevented%3Fh.%24%24parse(a)%3A(d.url(h.absUrl()%2Cb)%2Cg(a))%7D))%3Bh.%24%24replace%3D!1%3Breturn%20n%7D%3B%20newVal%3A%2010%3B%20oldVal%3A%209%22%5D%2C%5B%22fn%3A%20function()%7Bvar%20a%3Dd.url()%2Cb%3Dh.%24%24replace%3Bn%26%26a%3D%3Dh.absUrl()%7C%7C(n%2B%2B%2Cc.%24evalAsync(function()%7Bc.%24broadcast(%5C%22%24locationChangeStart%5C%22%2C%5Cnh.absUrl()%2Ca).defaultPrevented%3Fh.%24%24parse(a)%3A(d.url(h.absUrl()%2Cb)%2Cg(a))%7D))%3Bh.%24%24replace%3D!1%3Breturn%20n%7D%3B%20newVal%3A%2011%3B%20oldVal%3A%2010%22%5D%5D)

Here is the routing I've used:

```
phoneApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
  function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $routeProvider
      .when('/sap.com~home~phonelist/pages/index.html', {
        templateUrl: '/sap.com~home~phonelist/pages/landing.html',
        controller: 'SearchController'
      })
      .when('/sap.com~home~phonelist/pages/', {
        templateUrl: '/sap.com~home~phonelist/pages/landing.html',
        controller: 'SearchController'
      })
      .when('/sap.com~home~phonelist/pages/singleEmployee/:id', {
        templateUrl: '/sap.com~home~phonelist/pages/singleEmployee.html',
        controller: 'SingleEmployeeController'

      });

      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  }]);
```

The base href in my index: `<base href="/" />`
and also the only repeat in the page:

```
<tr ng-repeat="employee in filteredEmployees = (employees | filter:search.currentFilter | orderBy:user.ordering:reverse)">
    <td> <a class="fakeLink" href="singleEmployee/{{$index}}">{{ employee.name }}</a></td>
    <td class="location">{{ employee.userID }}</td>
    <td class="district">{{ employee.department }}</td>
    <td class="jobTitle">{{ employee.jobTitle }}</td>
    <td class="emailAddress">{{ employee.email }}</td>
    <td class="workPhone"><a class="fakeLink" href="tel:{{employee.phone}}">{{ employee.phone }}</a></td>
</tr>
```

The page loads fine in Chrome, but when I try to pop it open in IE nothing loads. I've checked my html on the ng-repeat to make sure that I'm not calling a method that creates new arrays. The base href seems to be called endlessly when I inspect with developer tools. Any thoughts on what might be causing this error?

Comment: I think ``$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`` is the problem! Does it work, if you set it to ``false``?

Comment: you may need to use `hasPrefix` like `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');` which you will need it for ie8 & ie9

Comment: @BettySt changing it to false does not work and breaks it in chrome
@pankajparkar adding `hashprefix(`!`)  doesnt make a difference.

Comment: you mean changing it to ``false``?

Comment: Bad news. IE9 do not support HTML5 History API. That is what angular html5Mode uses. If you need your app to run on IE9 you need to switch back, @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22763599/ie-9-not-supporting-locationprovider-html5mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a combination of 2 issues. Number one, change

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

to

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
```

Betty in the comments is correct, there is an issue with IE using this for older versions. In addition to this, you need to create a new route for just `/`. If you're having issues with angular routes kicking in, you can call `otherwise` in addition to `when` for setting up your routes. There's more information on that style of routing in the [angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07#the-app-module).