# IE vs Firefox Links (hash vs htm5)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angular-ui-router

On my site i use html5mode history API for angular routing and when it's not supported it goes back to use hash mode. /#/

**html5 mode :** *http://www.main.com/something*

**hash mode (ex IE9) :** *http://www.main.com/#/something*

The problem being if a IE9 user paste a link (*www.main.com/#/something*) to a FF/Chrome user, its not gonna work.

how can i handle this? - so the URL (just the appearance of it at least) is identical/usable for both browser types ?

Comment: Does this help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30877527/angular-routing-causes-infinite-loop-in-ie

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the hashPrefix to "#":

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('#');
```