# removing angular hash and prefix from #anchor

Tags: javascript, angularjs

iam strugling to make a direct anchor link to a site. when ever i try to link to the id via:
https://www.somesite.com/cl/details/agents#20841

where #20841 is my anchor tag. 
Angular breaks the url and makes it: 
https://www.somesite.com/cl/details/agents#!#20841

 this works fine in chrome and firefox, but in internet explorer and edge it dosnt, so it "breaks" the url. Ive tried to change the prefix to "!", instead of "/".

Anyone have a work around for this problem?

Comment: from angular 1.5 its made as enable by default use $locationProvider.html5Mode(true/false);

Comment: trying to set $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); breaks some animation and such in internet explorer 9

Comment: how does it break any error or problems ?

Comment: yeah sorry for not elaborating, in internet explorer 9 it breaks some animations, for some reason.

Comment: may be this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22763599/ie-9-not-supporting-locationprovider-html5mode

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Angular 1.6, you can remove this prefix by adding this code to your config:

```
appModule.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

Note that it could [not be supported in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22763599/ie-9-not-supporting-locationprovider-html5mode) dues to HTML5 compatibilty.

See [this link](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#commit-aa077e8) for more information.

Comment: making it even more annoying, iam not able to use version 1.6, so adding this bit of code just gives me the initial problem with angular routes so the hash becomes #/20841

Comment: if do this $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!'); my anchor becomes #!#20841  if i do this $locationProvider.hashPrefix(''); it falls back to default value and the anchor becomes #/20841

Comment: sorry didnt understand then, i want to remove the #! so i only have a valid anchor. so #!#20481 becomes #20481

Comment: Ok, so also add this line `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: as stated in my above comments, i can run html5mode, because it breaks some animations in internet explorer 9

Comment: Does the [first link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22771095/4927984) I provided helps you?

Comment: nope, if i go with that solution, i will still have the problem when using internet explorer. with the wrong #!# format