# IE9 and angular routing issues

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

This will be a bit long, but i hope to make myself clear. Please ask if i've not explained a point well enough.

Using the following structure/setup, i've h\got everything to work in all browsers except IE9. For anything below, i don't need to provide support; the problem therefore lies with EI9. I am not using UI-router.

1. Website URL `http://domainname`
2. Internal page link 1 `<a href="page1">page1</a>` - clicking on this should land me to `http://domainname/page1`
3. Internal page link 2 `<a href="page2">page2</a>` - clicking on this should land me to `http://domainname/page2`
4. Base `<base href="/">`
5. HTML5 mode enable `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)`
6. Relevant route config

`.when('/',{
     templateUrl : 'pages/homepage.html',
     controller : 'homepageController'
}).when('/page1',{
     templateUrl : 'pages/page1.html',
     controller : 'page1Controller'
}).when('page2',{
     templateUrl : 'pages/page2.html',
     controller : 'page2Controller'
})`

5. PhP htaccess redirect
   `RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule . index.php [L]` - this is for when you go to the page directly, and not land on the index, thus not giving the routing mechanism a chance to take over

**My IE9 problem**

The above Website URL gets transformed into `http://domainname/#/` - a `/#/` gets inserted into the link - i want that gone because it causes the following issues:

1. When accessing `<a href="page1">page1</a>` - the link i get sent to becomes `http://domainname/#/page1` - but it load fine. The problem becomes evident when trying to access the `page2` page from `page1`
2. When accessing `<a href="page2">page2</a>` - the link i get sent to becomes
   `http://domainname/#/page1/page2`, when it should at the very worst be `http://domainname/#/page2` - Angular adds the URL to the existing URL, as a sort of subroute. So on and so forth for other pages - the URL concatenates.

I'm thinking it's related to the fact that IE9 does not support HTML5 push/pop, which i'm guessing Angular uses. I'm not sure, i'm new to this. At the very least `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` is what's bugging IE9, from what i can tell.

I am currently stuck and will appreciate any help on the matter.

**EDIT:** The answer below IS a workable solution and i'll accept it a "solved issue" answer after further investigation. If you have the same issue, use it.

Comment: IE9 do not support the history API so I do not think you will get ti to work the way youd like. http://caniuse.com/#feat=history

Comment: That was my take on it as well, however the Angular website says it offers support for IE9, therefore i'm guessing there must be another mode to configure angular. I can check browser History API and switch depending on support, but i'm not familiar with a way to configure Angular to not use History API, without having to change the structure of all my links.

Comment: I see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17829991/angularjs-how-to-remove-symbol-in-ie9-by-using-route that using  window.location.hash = '/'  might help. Worth a try?

Comment: @aCa Definitely worth a try. Will test it out later and if it woks, i'll let you know. Thank you!

Comment: @aca Nope, using the solution provided there's absolutely no change.

Comment: @RaduAndrei Do you solve your problem? I have the same issue. Also I tried `window.location.hash = '/' `, it didn't help.

Comment: @Qianyue No, i didn't manage to, unfortunately.

Comment: @RaduAndrei Can you look at my answer? I think it should resolve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created this pluncker [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/4EVBUQ) for the angular 1.3 routing issue under ie9. You can run this example under ie9, it runs well.

Notice that the plunker example set the `<base href = ""/>` with `document.location` dynamically. For your contatenated url problem, I think that it may be the problem of `<base href>`. Setting to `<base href="/" />` should resolve the problem.

I also create a repo in github for this issue (in fact, it is a problem of infinite $digest issue, but routing still works, see [#9235](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9235)). Your can test this [sample](https://github.com/xie-qianyue/showcase-angular1.3-route-bug-ie9). In this sample I set `<base href="/app/" />`, because the base url is `app`.

Hope help.

Comment: Half way there i'd say. There's still the #/ added to the URL issue in ie9. IT IS a workable solution for a lack of a better alternative. Will circle back to this when my time allows to investigate further. Thank you for your help and for now, grab the up-vote :)

Comment: @RaduAndrei thx. Adding the hash isn't the  problem, the  routing will work fine. The  problem  is the  infinite  digest which may  consume the  ressources.