# pages not loading properly and a '#' is added in my url only in IE9

Tags: cross-browser, web-deployment

I am struggling with loading web pages in IE9

When I load a page of my web site, for example, www.xxxxxx.com,
It works well most of browser such as IE10, 11, Chrome, FireFox etc. 
However only in IE9, it becomes www.xxxxxx.com/# . automatically '#' is added to the url. Is there any thing that are not supported or something in IE9.

I am using HTML, SCSS, jQuery and ReactJS.

Comment: I'm guessing it has to do with something happening on load. Without some code and the version #s for react and jquery, it's hard to even know where to start looking.

Comment: I found a similar problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17829991/angularjs-how-to-remove-symbol-in-ie9-by-using-route but still don't know how to solve :( any comment?

Comment: Check out this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25086832/how-to-stop-in-browser-with-react-router  It looks like it is definitely something in the Location History API. I googled "react location api ie9" (no quotes) to find that -- other threads may have more answers. Sorry I can't be of more help.